# Can you bounce thin servers instead of restarting them all at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

This sucks:

```
$ thin restart -p 4000 -s 3 -d;
Stopping server on 0.0.0.0:4000 ... 
Sending QUIT signal to process 13375 ... 
>> Exiting!
Stopping server on 0.0.0.0:4001 ... 
Sending QUIT signal to process 13385 ... 
>> Exiting!
Stopping server on 0.0.0.0:4002 ... 
Sending QUIT signal to process 13397 ... 
>> Exiting!
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:4000 ... 
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:4001 ... 
Starting server on 0.0.0.0:4002 ...
```

Is there a way to cycle through each server and restart one at a time?

Comment: how about unicorn instead?

Comment: Contract work - I don't typically use thin, I use unicorn. But their requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rtm

```
> thin
Command required
Usage: thin [options] start|stop|restart|config

[...]

Cluster options:
    -s, --servers NUM                Number of servers to start
    -o, --only NUM                   Send command to only one server of the cluster
    -C, --config FILE                Load options from config file
    -O, --onebyone                   Restart the cluster one by one (only works with restart command)
```